# Send 'ACK' character over serial

Tags: c#

i set up a serial connection between 2 laptops. In the first one there is a program that send parameters to the other laptop. In the second laptop there is a c# program that receives these parameters and respond with characters 'A' followed by 'ACK' (in the ASCII table) if data is correct.

i have tried setting:

```
char bufferTX = new bufferTX[2];

bufferTX[0] = '\u0041';
bufferTX[1] = '\u0006';
```

but doesn't work because the character encoding takes too many bytes. I only need a byte for character 'A' and a byte for character 'ACK' ( HEX code 0x06). Anyone knows how to do it? i'm using c#.

Comment: You simply fumbled the declaration, it is `char[] bufferTX = new char[2];`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why just don't use `byte` instead of `char` (which is unicode character in .NET)?

```
var buffer = new byte[]
{
    0x41,
    0x06
};
```